# Does an analytic $f$ need be polynomial to close $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: rational-numbers, analytic-functions

If an analytic function $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(\mathbb{Q}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$, can we conclude that $f$ is a polynomial?

Comment: Obviously not. Try $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$

Comment: ^That is not analytic.

Comment: @ElliotG Yes it is, it's meromorphic with poles at $\pm i$, so it's analytic on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ElliotG Looks analytic to me. For what $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ can you not find a power series expansion about $x_0$?

Comment: Never mind; used complex definition.

Comment: @ElliotG What is the real definition that you think the function fails to satisfy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is analytic but not a polynomial.